# Improve a loop by using a method on an object

Tags: java

I would like to improve my code below (which works):

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Personnage> personnages = new ArrayList<Personnage>();
    personnages.add(new Personnage("Eric", "Super Sayan", 50, 3, true));
    personnages.add(new Personnage("Juliette", "Sayan", 45, 7, true));

    int count = 1;
    for(Personnage personnage : personnages){
        personnage.affichage(count++);
      }
    
    }

}
```

Firstly, I want to create a method to count my personnages.

```
int count = 1;
    for(Personnage personnage : personnages){
        personnage.affichage(count++);
    }
```

I have this for now:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Personnage> personnages = new ArrayList<Personnage>();
    personnages.add(new Personnage("Eric", "Super Sayan", 50, 3, true));
    personnages.add(new Personnage("Juliette", "Sayan", 45, 7, true));

    loopPersonnage();

    }
    
    public static void loopPersonnage(){
      int count = 1;
      for(Personnage personnage : personnages){
        personnage.affichage(count++);
      }
    
    }

}
```

Except that, I have as error message:

```
Main.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
      for(Personnage personnage : personnages){
```

Do have you an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: you have a problem of understanding scopes in java. if you want to work with your `personnages` object you should pass his reference to method `loopPersonnage`, your method should look like this `public static void loopPersonnage(List<Personnage> personnages)`

Comment: This is because `personnages` is not *in scope* (and you should be glad it isn't). That is because `personnages` is a variable *local* to the `main` method. I suggest you [read more about variable scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope).

Comment: Thank very much, my problem is solved. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass "personnages" into your "loopPersonnage" method.

```
public static void loopPersonnage( List< Personnage > personnages ){ … }
```

And:

```
loopPersonnage( personnages );
```